# Generator like stream from RxJS from JS Map

Tags: rxjs, observable, generator, rxjs6

I have created a `new Map()` which is `<string, string>`. I have created an `Rx.Observable` from it. `Rx.from(Map)`. Say it has 5 entries.

I want to be able to consume the entries 1 at a time and on demand. So I take the first entry, which is a string, and send it as a message. I wait for a reply and if the reply is `OK` I take the second entry and send it, and so on.

```
const source: Rx.Observable<[string, string]> = Rx.from(myMap);

function handleSending(): void {
    source.pipe(map((x: any) => x.join(''))).subscribe((x: string) => client.write(x));
}
```

This implementation pulls all the entries in a continuous stream, where as I want to take one and wait. I think what I need is the functionality of a generator but I am unsure how to do this in RxJS

Comment: You want to wait for what? Until `client.write(x)` is done? What does this call return?

Comment: `client` is a `net.Socket`. I wait for the other server to respond with `OK` or `DENY`. If `OK` then I send pull the next Map entry and send the next item.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test it but there's [`bindNodeCallback`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindNodeCallback) method that wraps a Node's function and returns another function that returns Observables. Then `concatMap` won't process a new item until the current inner Observable completes.

So in your use-case you could use for example this:

```
const obsWrite = bindNodeCallback(client.write);

source
  .pipe(
    map((x: any) => x.join('')),
    concatMap((x: string) => obsWrite(x))
  )
  .subscribe();
```